# Creación de pruebas unitarias con usuarios logueados

Tags: php, laravel, pruebas-unitarias

Quiero hacer una prueba al siguiente método de mi controller

```
function index(){
        if(Auth::User()->can('view_roles'))
        {
            $roles = Role::all();
            return response()->json(['data' => $roles], 200);
        }

        return response()->json(['Not_authorized'], 401);
    }
```

ya está configurado todo para la autentificación (tymondesigns/jwt-auth) y el manejo de los roles (spatie/laravel-permission), haciendo pruebas con Postman sí funciona, solo que quiero hacerlo de forma automatizada.

Este es es el código del test, si quito el condicional de la función del controller el TEST pasa, pero quisiera hacer una prueba usando un usuario pero no tengo idea de como realizarlo.

```
public function testIndexRole()
{
    $this->json('GET', '/role')->seeJson([
        'name' => 'admin',
        'name' => 'secratary'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que no te estás autenticando un usuario y en el método estas requiriendo que el usuario esté autenticado y si no esta autenticado responda un status 401.
Por lo tanto jamás vas a poder ver la data o un status 200.
Tu test debería ser algo así.

```
use RefreshDatabase;

public function testIndexRole()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->json('GET', '/role')
        ->assertJson([
            'data' => [
                'name' => 'admin',
                'name' => 'secratary'
            ]
        ])
        ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Fijate de mirar un poco la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#session-and-authentication), siempre ayuda

La otra opción sería cuando el usuario no está autenticado

```
public function testIndexRoleConUsuarioNoAutenticado()
{
    $this->json('GET', '/role')
        ->assertJson(['Not_authorized'])
        ->assertStatus(401);
}
```